# How can I hide an icon related to a mount point. Question about "x-gvfs-show"

Tags: mount, icons

My question is related to adding `x-gvfs-show` to `/etc/fstab` when I mount a folder to another folder using `bind` option.

**Long story short**, I have a number of applications installed via snap. As my home directory has limited capacity, I had to move snap folder to somewhere else, via `mount --bind /path/to/snap /home/myaccount/snap` as the only working way. I actually added `/etc/fstab` entry:

```
/mnt/data/.localfiles/ziko-locals/snap   /home/ziko/snap   none   defaults,bind   0 0
```

Although everything is great, I have an icon on Destop. I found `x-gvfs-show` could be set, somehow, to hide the icon on getting mounted but I can't find any explanation how to do so.

Comment: You may need to use `x-gvfs-hide` rather than `x-gvfs-show` for your case. I have also seen `comment=x-gvfs-hide` but there is [some contention](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/235437/110698) about that.

Answer (score 0):

`x-gvfs-hide` is the option you want to *hide* the icon. In `etc/fstab`, you add it to the existing options, as in

```
/mnt/data/.localfiles/ziko-locals/snap   /home/ziko/snap   none   defaults,bind,x-gvfs-hide   0 0
```

Actually, `defaults` could optionally be removed: it is only used as a placeholder if no specific options are provided.

Comment: I added `x-gvfs-hide` to options but it doesn't work. I also tried to remove `defaults`. I am on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS BTW. I also tested `comment=x-gvfs-hide`, `comment=x-gvfs-show`, etc. I tried many things but mounting always add this icon. To avoid restarting, is `mount --bind -o x-gvfs-hide /path1 /path2` equivalent? I did restart machine for tests.

Comment: Might be buggy behaviour indeed: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glib2.0/+bug/1691908

Comment: I see. Is it fixed in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Comment: If I see the bug report, not yet.